# Squeeze theorem for functions given by infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a series representation of a function $f(\varepsilon,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\varepsilon,x)$ and I want to study the behaviour of $f$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. For a fixed $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small, and every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the function $f$ is well defined and further $a_n(\varepsilon,x)\geq 0$ for each $n$. Given that $f(\varepsilon,x)\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)$ where $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}a_n(\varepsilon,x)=b_n(x)$ would I be correct in saying that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}a_n(\varepsilon,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)\leq\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\varepsilon,x)\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)$$
and thus
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\varepsilon,x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)$$
or is there more that would need to be checked? I suspect there may be some issues in this argument. Namely the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)$ need not converge however it is unclear to me where this issue is arising.

Comment: 1) Why should $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\varepsilon,x)$ exist, and why should it be $\ge\sum b_n(x)?$ 2) Your post would be more readable without that (fixed!) "variable" $x:$ $f(\varepsilon)=\sum a_n(\varepsilon), \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}a_n(\varepsilon)=b_n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I am attempting to use some sort of squeeze theorem argument here. The lowet bound comes from an application of Fatou's Lemma I believe using the fact that $a_n(\varepsilon,x)\to b_n(x)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Oh yes, I agree now! $\sum b_n\le\liminf\dots\le\limsup\dots\le\sum b_n$ (even if $\sum b_n=+\infty$).